# How do I get a user's email address (with permission) on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, email, contacts, addressbook

Typing on iPhone is tedious; I'd like to prompt my users for their email address without requiring them to actually type it.

Ideally they'd receive a dialog saying: "This app would like to use your email address.  Don't Allow / Allow"

If the user tapped "Allow," it would auto-fill their email address (the one they have configured in Mail.app) in a text field.

Is this possible?

Comment: If I picked "Allow" which one of my email addresses would it use? quixoto's answer is good because it also bypasses that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. But you can load up the contact picker interface and ask the user to select themselves from it-- that's much more friendly than making them type it in.

More info here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/200-QuickStart/QuickStart.html

Comment: Adding this comment because most assume one thing in this approach (that the email is verified, which is not the case).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, have a look at [ABGetMe](https://github.com/0xced/ABGetMe) for iOS. Note that you would have to write the allow/don’t allow dialog yourself. Also, make sure to read and understand the *Limitations* section of the README.